# Check if a given app is installed in android work profile?

Tags: android, react-native

I have two apps on my android phone - X and Y. X is installed in my personal profile and Y is installed in my work profile on my android. How can I check if Y is installed on my phone programatically from application X using react native?

I have used the plugin react-native-check-app-install and it works only if both X and Y are installed in the same profile. I have included the package name of Y in Queries tag and also enabled the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file in application X.

Comment: Surely the point of profiles is to isolate the two environments?